# Area change error moluscle

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error, debugging

I want to simulate future LULC change using QGIS 2.18.24 Molusce plugin. When I was running update tables option under area change, I got a python error message shown on the screenshot below.

How can I correct it?

[image: molusce area change error]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Questions should always contain error messages as text. Images are not legible on all devices and cannot be searched by others (effectively hiding it, wrecking the whole point of answering). Please [Edit] the Question.